# Configuring Default Spring Boot app to render HTML pages and CSS JS content

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I configured a Basic Spring Boot app containing Hibernate. However, no page is being rendered.

I have places my pages in src/main/resources/templates/ and content(CSS and JS) in src/main/resources/static/

I have added Thymeleaf through Maven and written a basic controller to render my page -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/testui")
public class GreetingController {

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "greeting";
}
```

}

Instead of rendering a page with my name, it is rendering the string - "greeting"

I have placed the greeting.html in templates file. What are the changes in application.properties I need to make to render pages (what keys and values must I give?)

Update - I somehow do not have the webapp folder. Added that. Created a folder called jsp and added a simple page. Referenced it - didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why is it not working?

Because you are using `@RestController`. `@RestController` is used to create API controllers which serve JSON/XML, whereas `@Controller` is used to create controllers which serve web content such as HTML.

#### Proposed solution

Replace `@RestController` with `@Controller`. For further details, please see the official [Getting Started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) guide of Spring.

Comment: I changed that and added the following entries to my application.properties file -

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

It still didn render the page

Answer (score 0):

You've added `@RestController` on the Controller class, which means that you want all values returned by the controller methods to be considered as response body (that's the equivalent of annotating all controller methods with `@ResponseBody`).

Remove that annotation from the class and replace it with `@Controller` and you should get the expected result.

Comment: I tried.. Didnt work. Created webapps folder , placed a small HTML page and also put in these in properties file

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

It still didnt work

Comment: Your question mentions thymeleaf. Your thymeleaf templates should go in src/main/resources/templates. If you want to use JSPs, please take a look at the reference documentation as it’s harder to set up.